# What is the maximum score one can score from one ball?

Tags: cricket

Hit a no ball and run 4 runs. Then the fielder will throw that ball and it will go for a six..total 11 runs.

Is that possible?

Comment: Even though I agreed for close vote, I am wondering how would it be a duplicate since other questions are about scoring in one over and this one is about scoring in one ball. This is just a related question and not a duplicate one.

Comment: @ACB you should've considered that before closing the question. I find closing questions a serious matter.

Comment: I think that is why there is a reopen option. Unlike a downvote, you can always reopen a question which is closed. When I casted close vote, there was already a few comments on that and felt genuine. But when we read it on title, you can see that it is different. People should be more careful with downvotes which cant be reversed. Even if it is a duplicate doesn't mean that you have to downvote. It should be based on the quality of question.

Comment: @ACB this question had severe grammar problems. You could've closed it as "it's unclear what's being asked here", but you decided to go with the flow. Please pay more attention when closing questions.

Comment: Grammar problems don't mean that you need to close it. You can always edit the question and correct it. And closing is done by 5 people, not just one. People need to be careful with where they are using their down votes though. That is the major problem here.

Comment: @ACB From the [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote): *"Voting up...signals...that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post...contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information."* The reason for downvotes does fall in the category of "fails to communicate information," which would not be an improper use of voting. However, as you state, we can and should help users improve their questions before voting-down or closing.

Comment: @edmastermind29, Yes, I understand that _"fails to communicate information"_ is a valid reason for downvote. But how will you explain the two downvotes on my answer below. It doesn't fall on any of those reasons and this is not the first time I am getting downvote for no reason(not just sports.se but in other sites too). That was my point here. If it fails to communicate information, the most suitable thing to do is, to add a comment below asking for explanation. I have never seen anyone here doing that. A blind downvote is not going to help anyone here.

Comment: @ACB I fully agree with your statement. However, that is **ideal** behavior. I have [experienced](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/what-advantages-do-long-and-belly-putters-have-over-traditional-putters) your frustration.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically it is possible to score as many runs as possible since none of the cricket laws are putting a limit on that. So the answer is infinity.

And yes, what you have mentioned is possible. But if a fielder throws the ball after picking from the ground it won't be a six, but a four. So it will be 9 runs.